# Passing argument to mpg123 with subprocess in a python script

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

I have a Python3 script that responds to input from a rotary dial phone (via GPIO pins on a raspberry pi.)  If I dial a `1`, my script uses `subprocess` to tell `mpg123` to play a file called `1.mp3`.  `2` plays `2.mp3`, and so on up to 7.  This is working:

```
filename = "/media/"+str(number)+".mp3"
player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123",  filename, "-q"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If I dial `8`, the magic 8-ball, the script should behave differently.  I want it to call mpg123 with the "little shuffle" flag, `-z`.  From the command line, I know how to make that call:

```
 mpg123 -z /media/mp3s/*
```

I want to use this exact syntax in my python3 script, but it isn't working.

```
 if number ===8:
         player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "-z", "/media/mp3s/*"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Nothing happens.  Script just waits patiently for the next non-8 input.

As a Plan B, I thought maybe I could pass a list of files to mpg123 with `glob.glob`:

```
filelist = glob.glob('/media/mp3s/*.mp3')
print(filelist)
player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "-z", "--list", filelist], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This crashes the script because `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`  (Though it does successfully print out the list of files before it dies.)  I think I must be very close with at least one approach, but I can't figure out the last little bit of syntax.  Any ideas appreciated.**

---

Alright - I figured out a way to make it work, using mpg123's builtin directory specifying flag, `-B`.  I am still curious about how to get one or both of my other approaches to work.  For the record, this works:

`player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "-Bz", "/media/mp3s/"],.......`

Comment: for plan B `cmds = ['mpg123', '-z', '--list']` and `cmds.extend(filelist)` and `subprocess.Popen(cmds, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is probably better, however I thought I would point out the problem with your plan B:

```
filelist = glob.glob('/media/mp3s/*.mp3')
print(filelist)
player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "-z", "--list", filelist], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem here is you are passing `filelist` as an item to the list. So you would get a list containing a list:

```
["mpg123", "-z", "--list", [ '/media/mp3s/1.mp3', '/media/mp3s/2.mp3' ]]
```

However what you wanted is this:

```
["mpg123", "-z", "--list", '/media/mp3s/1.mp3', '/media/mp3s/2.mp3']
```

To get these you need to join the lists together:

```
player = subprocess.Popen(["mpg123", "-z", "--list"] + filelist, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Not tested, but I believe this should work.

Answer (score 1):

To fix approach A, you'll need to set `shell=True` to get wildcard support. The command itself should then be a string instead of a list however:

```
if number ===8:
     player = subprocess.Popen("mpg123 -z /media/mp3s/*", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The docs mention this behavior near the bottom of this section:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

The difference is that without the shell flag, python is running the first entry in the list as the command and using the rest as arguments (the `*` taken literally). With the shell flag, the entire string is plopped in and the shell is allowed to do what it will. I can't reproduce this exact case but I imagine the command tries to run and fails to find a file called `/media/mp3s/*`.

I would argue however that your final solution is more pythonic however and you should stick with that. Specifying `shell=True` generally just means that the python built-ins that accomplish filename expansion, etc. aren't being utilized (examples of these listed in the same doc listed above).